# After creating new user on MYSQL and trying to login with root -> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

On docker, using docker-compose, image: mysql:5.7.22, and envs like:

```
environment:
     MYSQL_USER: myuser_admin
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: myuser
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
     MYSQL_DATABASE: my_table
```

after accessing mysql through root user and creating a new user through this commands:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myuser';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_table.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I exit mysql terminal inside docker and try to login with root user again, i get this message on the title:

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

What should this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my friend and i found the problem.

On my dump from another database the root user had a diferent password.

So as i dumped into mine, and run the FLUSH PRIVILEGES, my new user changed its password, automatically